# PNG Sequence Animation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, animation

So I currently have this code in my oncreate. I really want to create an animation as soon as the user opens the app using a png sequence.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list_filling);
    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
```

And..

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        frameAnimation.start();
    } else {
        frameAnimation.stop();
    }
}
```

And I have created an xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item
        android:duration="100"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tugs_00000"/>

    <item
        android:duration="100"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tugs_00001"/>

    <item
        android:duration="100"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tugs_00002"/>

...
    <item
        android:duration="100"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tugs_00043"/>
</animation-list>
```

But once I run the app, it keeps on crashing. There were no errors in Android Studio present.

Comment: Karla Romero can you send me your crash log